# How to read a plain txt file and convert to json using python?

Tags: python, json, csv

**My current code:**

```
try:
    recipients = { 'HBRj6x6huUKyWtuv643DRrrCbkd2kDj2Z6': 50.0
                 , 'HNGY9f6Hh6uiVYcoGUnW3xCRVToBP9LujR': 50.0
                 , 'HPcWvavNTR1qywMzq1figttGddHnMGHGWx': 50.0
                 , 'H88DbndzTeN66Q9RyVeiPsDYWwevJph3Lx': 50.0
                 , 'HG818gFwAVfNGZKT8F9qv9aj2du7QZEuMP': 50.0
                 , 'HFY7mMZuUcohP3bgLAnQrLxuWxDqcXEydW': 50.0
                 , 'HBrvtTteTARdehFYWYmok4HaQp3TvFiGGw': 50.0
                 , 'HMT7agiynUhR656GTaRUsHndSEFQVR2n2D': 50.0
                 , 'HNrvbV9aqRnJ6ZJ1e9sY9CDsJFqoTFaFch': 50.0
                 , 'HQBiwms9cVrcVFJ2fKVbhab666JePeRTnz': 50.0
                 }
    bitcoind.sendmany("", recipients)
```

im trying to read `recipients JSON` from a plain txt file that has a list like this :

```
HBRj6x6huUKyWtuv643DRrrCbkd2kDj2Z6
HNGY9f6Hh6uiVYcoGUnW3xCRVToBP9LujR
HPcWvavNTR1qywMzq1figttGddHnMGHGWx
H88DbndzTeN66Q9RyVeiPsDYWwevJph3Lx
HG818gFwAVfNGZKT8F9qv9aj2du7QZEuMP
HFY7mMZuUcohP3bgLAnQrLxuWxDqcXEydW
HBrvtTteTARdehFYWYmok4HaQp3TvFiGGw
HMT7agiynUhR656GTaRUsHndSEFQVR2n2D
HNrvbV9aqRnJ6ZJ1e9sY9CDsJFqoTFaFch
HQBiwms9cVrcVFJ2fKVbhab666JePeRTnz
```

How do I programmatically convert that plain txt to look like JSON ( adding ( `{ ' : and 50.0 etc` )? I've tried this :

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

try:
    recipients = (data)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\sendmany.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.load(data_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: That looks more like a hash than like JSON to me. I'm pretty sure your file does not contain JSON data

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, yes, the plain text file have hash in each new line.

Comment: So are you trying to figure out how to get the value that created each hash?

Comment: Need some clarification here. I *think* you are saying you want to convert a plain text to json. Are you saying the file in your code snippet named "data.jsoin" is supposed to be your "plain text" input file?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget , what im doing is: send 50 to each recipient, each hash =  a recipient, to do that it must look like { 'hash': amount, ...} JSON ?, i want to be able to read those hashes from plain text and programmatically add the amount and { ' : , }

Comment: @AndrewAllaire yes thats correct, the plain text file is data.json ( none json data inside it)

Comment: So if you want to read each input line as the key to a dictionary, assign a value to each in your own way, and then output the dictionary in pretty json text?

Comment: @AndrewAllaire im trying my best to find a better way to clarify , i do not want to output json, i want to processes those text file lines(hashes) to json then  try: bitcoind.sendmany("",  { 'hash': amount, 'hash': amount,...} )

Comment: I am not familiar with what bitcoind.sendmany does. However the json.dumps() value in both my answer and in Inspector's answer will be a string in json you can pass to it. For my answer I made the string human readable and pretty, but I am guessing that doesn't matter, so you don't have to put the extra args in the call to json.dumps()

Comment: ok adjusted my answer, took out the pretty formatting of the json sting, and passing it to that function instead of to output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_value(hash_value)
    """Function to return approriate value."""
    return 50

receipt_dict = {}
with open("data.json", "r") as plain_text:
    for line in plain_text:
        hash_value = line.strip()
        receipt_dict[hash_value] = get_value(hash_value)

json_string = json.dumps(receipt_dict)

try:
     bitcoind.sendmany("", json_string)
...
```

Comment: great it works, however, when it come to the try: part it throw this : Error: value is type str, expected obj, any idea ?

Comment: found out that the output is : {"H7zEUSuKKRzvK7BkPiHuHApGo4HnaCuGbV": "50",..} it must be like this : {'H7zEUSuKKRzvK7BkPiHuHApGo4HnaCuGbV': 50,...} , how to change " to ' and remove " from 50 ?

Comment: I am not familiar with bitcoind.sendmany, but it seems the code for it is here: https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/bitcoin/rpc.py with a quick look at it, it seems you might want to simply pass receipt_dict instead of json_string.

Comment: {"H7zEUSuKKRzvK7BkPiHuHApGo4HnaCuGbV": "50",..} seems to mean a python dictionary (which looks very similar to a json), with the value being a string "50" as opposed to the other expression where the value seems to be the integer 50. In the code snippet I provided just change what is returned by the get_value() function. If you make it return "50", you will get the string. As is, you will get the integer.

Comment: Thank you very much, as the value is fixed 50, what i did is simply:  receipt_dict[hash_value] = 50 , and removed the def get_value(hash_value).. everything is great now. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward, by building a data structure (e.g. a dictionary) from the lines of the file, and then using `json.dumps()` to convert it to JSON:

```
import json

requests = {}
with open('data.json') as infile:  # though that data really isn't in JSON format
    for line in infile:
        requests[line.strip()] = 50


# now to JSON stuff with `answer`

print(json.dumps(answer))
```

Comment: You mean `requests[line.strip()] = 50`?